# Joining two tables in the dataset

Tags: vb.net

I am having a data set in vb.net with two tables one table is filled by using oracle databse and another one from Sql 2005. How can we join these two tables in the dataset

Comment: Do try have the same number of columns

Answer (score 1):

Is that what are you looking for:

[How to join two DataTables using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4)

Comment: I assumed that you can get vb code from the c# code in the topic I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use VB .Net Linq to join the 2 datasets so long as they have compatible record properties.

Here's a decent MSDN article covering the VB .Net implementation;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx